# How to make SOCAT send each character from STDIO?

Tags: serial-port, putty, fifo, socat

I have the following scenario:

I have a Windows in a VM, which has an exposed serial port to a host pipe (named-pipe / fifo).

The host pipe is at `/tmp/win-serial-com3`.

On my host OS, I'm using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) like so:

```
socat - /tmp/win-serial-com3,cr
```

On the guest, I'm opening [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html), and set "implicit LF in every CR", and local echo is enabled. PuTTY opens COM3 on that guest Windows.

With both running, return keys work fine, there is no doubling, etc. I can type into the PuTTY and I can see each character appear one after another in the terminal in my host OS, where `socat` is running.

However, when I type something in my host OS, I can see the local echo (as it is not switched off with `echo=0` option), but the character will appear in PuTTY on my guest os, only after hitting return.

What I'd like to happen, is that each time I press a key, that key is sent to the named pipe, essentially having the same behavior as PuTTY on the guest OS.

I assume this has something to do with buffering of STDIO (`-`), but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found the solution, and it took quite a bit of trial and error:

On the host side (Linux), this is how `socat` has to be invoked:

```
stty -icanon && socat - /tmp/win-serial-com3,cr
```

On the Guest side, PuTTY has to be invoked with "Implicit LF in every CR", and unset "Implicity CR in every LF", in the "Terminal" settings.

It's still not ideal.

When I press <kbd>backspace</kbd> on the host side, it prints a `^?`, instead of erasing the previous character. On the guest side, this works alright. When pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> on the guest side, it erases the characters on the guest side, but not on the host side. I have yet to find a way to get <kbd>backspace</kbd> working.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution to the backspace issue?

Comment: @Joffrey nope. I haven't pursued the issue further, though. However I plan to get back to it eventually.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but trying something like stty -icanon && socat "stdin,raw,echo=0,escape=0x11" <socket> seems to get all working including backspace

Comment: @rajasaur will try that soon. I haven't been doing a lot recently with it, but I surely want that solution to be on record.

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm for me. My goal was to emulate the behavior of a telnet terminal with socat, and this did it.

Comment: I found that @rajasaur's `stdin` invocation was necessary when running `socat` through a Unix domain socket to a pfSense VM. This is a huge help.